# I am generating signal and facing the strange behaviour

Tags: c, linux, systems-programming

I have started getting my hands of signals in Linux but here is some strange behavior happening in my code. I have just started and I searched for it too but I have not found anything, sorry if the question is too lame, here is the code-

```
void Handler(int sig ){
    printf("Inside Handler\n");
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[], char * envp[]){
    if( signal(SIGINT, Handler) ==SIG_ERR )
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    for(size_t i = 0; ; i++){
        printf("%d\n", i);
        sleep(2);
    }
}
```

I know `printf`, `signal` calls are not the good idea to use but I have not studied `sigaction` till now. Now according to my book and others tutorial if I press `ctrl+c` then it has to call `Handler` every time but here is the strange thing: when I am pressing `ctrl+c` once, it's calling `Handler` but the next time it's terminating the program. Why is this strange thing happening?

Comment: printf("Inside Handler\n"): <-- semicolon

Comment: See [How to avoid using `printf()` in a signal handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler/) for some discussion/commentary on the wisdom of your signal handler.

Comment: Note that what you see depends on the platform you're using.  You're using Linux which behaves as you describe (the signal handler is reset), but BSD and macOS behave differently (the signal handler is not reset) — and the standards (POSIX and C) sanction both sets of behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code which I have written with your help which is working perfectly fine and I believe this will work nicely in each and every platform

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

void Handler(int sig ){
printf("Inside Handler\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[] ){
sighandler_t Action =Handler;

if( Action == SIG_DFL ){
Action = Handler;
}

if( signal(SIGINT, Action ) == SIG_ERR )
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE );

for(size_t k = 0 ; ; k++ ){
 printf("%d\n", k );
 sleep(2);
}

}
```

Comment: Which platform did you test it on?

Comment: Linux , ubuntu.

Comment: OK.  And what do you consider is covered by "each and every platform"?

Comment: Because there are only two issues which are mentioned in man page, they are i) if we are using `-std=cxx` or `-ansi` then `SIG_DFL` is gonna set automatically and ii) if handler function returns `SIG_DFL` is gonna set automatically, `_BSD_SOURCE` has improved this behavior but still again its depend on versions. So, according to me only problem is `SIG_DFL`  which we are handling in within `if`. The only problem I see in this is `sig_t` data type as `_BSD_SOURCE` provides this one. That something we can solve by using preprocessors. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The manual page for `signal` syscall says:

> If the signal signum is delivered to the process, then one of the following happens:
>
> - If the disposition is set to SIG_IGN, then the signal is ignored.
> - If the disposition is set to SIG_DFL, then the default action associated with the signal (see signal(7)) occurs.
> - *If  the disposition is set to a function, **then first either the disposition is reset to SIG_DFL, or the signal is blocked** (see Portability below), and then handler is called with argument signum.  If invocation of the handler caused the signal to be blocked, then the signal is unblocked upon return from the handler.*

Since the default behavior of SIGINT is to terminate once the signal is reset to default behavior, the subsequent behavior is different.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of `signal` when passed a handler other than `SIG_DFL` or `SIG_IGN` is undefined. Use `sigaction` for this purpose.

As the [docs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html#NOTES) say:

> The  only  portable use of signal() is to set a signal's disposition to `SIG_DFL` or `SIG_IGN`.  The semantics when using signal() to establish a signal handler vary across systems (and POSIX.1 explicitly permits this variation); do not use it for this purpose.